# How to define A type in Class A

Tags: c++, class

```
class A
{
     public:
         A a;
         int b;
         CString c;
}
```

a type A inside A class

So if i want to define a Type of class name in the same class, what should i do .

Thanks

Comment: Stop wanting to do that?

Comment: You can only have pointers to this class inside the definition.

Comment: visit [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Think about how this could ever work. You have an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an `A` object, within an

Comment: Remember that in C++, unlike in Java, members of a class are always occupying space *inside* the class object. They are not being held by reference when you define them as `A a;`. To have an object refer to another object of its own type, you must use a (smart-)pointer or a reference, with the latter having some more caveats.

Answer (score 0):

What about using a smart pointer to the object A, after you have defined the A object in the main program?
I don't think you can make a recursive definition: it would end up with an infinite loop on calling the class' constructor.